# Developing Module for 1.5-1.9 on Single Code Base

Tags: module, magento-1.6, magento-1.5

I've developed a module for Magento and it's supposed to support the versions 1.5+. I've developed it in 1.9 and it works with 1.6+. 1.5 crashes when trying to install with this error.

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup' not found`

How can I support all the versions from a single code base if this class is not found?

Also 1.6 works fine but refuses to install from a package generated from 1.9. I tried generating the package in 1.6 and tried using this after cleaning up the Magento instance but no joy. Still the same issue:

`CONNECT ERROR: Unsupported resource type`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to support 1.6CE+ only, or move to the old style `Namespace_Module_Model_Mysql4_...` resource classes, `Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_...` classes were only introduced from 1.6CE+.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, what about the code which works with 1.6 when uploaded via FTP but when attempted to install it via TGZ (packed in 1.6) fails? Any thoughts?

Comment: No reason that I know (off the top of my head) for a package generated under 1.9 not installing under 1.6.

Comment: Is there anyway to log the exception which occurs? The console in Connect is not giving more than `unsupported resource type` but nothing more.

Comment: Does it install with a clean instance of 1.6?

Comment: No that's the problem, set them up with sample data for testing purposes and it fails. According to system.log it fails in `get_resource_type() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given  in ~/magento16_sandbox/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Package/Reader.php on line 140`

Comment: I var_dumped the result of get_resource_type() into the console and this is the output
`string(4) "====" NULL NULL`
It's expecting `stream` otherwise it throws the exception.

Comment: Nevermind, got it, the parameter being passed into the `_loadResource` method is a `file handle` of the package. If opening the file fails then a `boolean(false)` is the handle and hence the error as it is expecting a proper file handle.